# IE8 treats json response as file and tries to download it

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, download

I am using IE8 and I am sending ajax request to on of the url which sends back response as json. The jquery code for the ajax setup is given below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: url_string,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
      alert('all is well');
    },
    error: function(request, status, error){
      alert(request);
      alert(status);
      alert(error);
    }
  });
});
```

I am sure that the server is sending JSON response but IE8 treats it as file and brings up download popup box. But the same process works fine for FF and Chrome. This still happens when i replace **json** to **jsonp** in **dataType**

But it always enters into error callback method.

My **json** response body consists of a string with **html tags** too.

Any idea why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: can you post the http response headers you're getting back from the server please?  Use Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to capture.  Oh, if that's going to an in-development website on `localhost` - you might have to change to using your machine name or ipv4.fiddler as the hostname once you have it running.

Comment: ok copy pasting response header form FF
Response Header
Date Tue, 17 Jan 2012 10:21:48 GMT
Server Apache/2.2.12 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By PHP/5.2.10-2ubuntu6.10
Access-Control-Allow-Orig... *
Content-Length 6507
Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Cache MISS from localhost
X-Cache-Lookup MISS from localhost:3128
Via 1.1 localhost:3128 (squid/2.7.STABLE9)
Connection keep-alive

Comment: and this is the response header that i got from fiddler
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Tue, 17 Jan 2012 11:45:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.12 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.10-2ubuntu6.10
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Cache: MISS from localhost
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from localhost:3128
Via: 1.1 localhost:3128 (squid/2.7.STABLE9)
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: This isn't specific to jQuery; hence it's a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943439/json-response-download-in-ie710).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue and fixed it by setting Content-type = "text/html" in the response header for all IE requests (rather than "application/json")

I also wrote a blog post about it with some more information: http://blog.degree.no/2012/09/jquery-json-ie8ie9-treats-response-as-downloadable-file/

Comment: +1 Thanks.  `text/plain` also works.  Looks like it's the same for IE8 and 9.  IE10 seems to grok `application/json`.

Comment: this prompts a redirect in mine.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what is sending the json, you have to send it as mime type text.
So in rails I had to do this.

```
    render :text => my_array.to_json
```

Instead of

```
    render :json => my_array
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the url of your code and used the latest version of JQuery and it runs fine within IE8 for me

```
<html> 
<head>   
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function() {            
    $.ajax({                      
        url: "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/groups_pool.gne?id=807213@N20&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
                    dataType: "json",                      
        success: function(response){                        
            alert('all is well');                      
            alert($.param(response));                 
        },                      
        error: function(request, status, error){                            
            alert(request);                            
            alert(status);                            
            alert(error);
        }          
});  
}); 
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

There is a known issue as detailed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925057/ie8-json-problem) where IE8 has problems with an extra comma in a result array. Check the contents of the response alert for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not solving my problem. My problem is, why IE8 downloaded the json response as a file. Content-Length of response header is 0 as the response is treated as a file.

Comment: Yes, I seen that in your comment added after I answered.