# IE8 prompts download json response

Tags: c#, jquery, json, internet-explorer-8, jquery-forms-plugin

I've been trying out the jquery form plugin and it works wonderfully. Oh, except for IE8. It's always ie8.

Anyways, on the success response callback, ie8 prompts me to download the response instead of actually calling the success function.

Here is what my javascript code looks like

```
 $("#form1").ajaxForm({
                url: "http://localhost:4887/api/file/POST",
                type: "POST",                 
                success: function (data)
                {
                    //response stuff here                   
                }
            });
```

I've tried specifying the datatype for the ajax form, but woe is me, it didn't work

The only thing I am returning from the server is just a string. Once again, IE8 prompts me to download this string instead of just calling the success function. After some research, I understand that I might have to modify the http headers? Could anyone shed some light on this? Or give another way of going about this?

UPDATE
Here is a brief look at the C# controller

```
public class fileController : ApiController
{     
    public JsonResult POST()
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = null; 


       string encodedString = //do stuff here to get the base64 string

        ModelName obj = new ModelName();

        obj.characters = encodedString;
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
        result.Data = obj;
        result.ContentType = "text/html";

        return result;

    }
```

Request Headers...

Accept  application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*

Accept-Language en-US

User-Agent  Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)

Content-Type    multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7dd3e622907b6

Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate

Proxy-Connection    Keep-Alive

Content-Length  300

Response Headers
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control   no-cache

Pragma  no-cache

Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8

Expires -1

Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.0

X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET

Comment: Can you monitor the request and response in Fiddler or the IE dev tools (I don't remember if IE8 had a working network tab). If you post the request and response headers, that may help.

Comment: Also, is this regular MVC or WebAPI? (Does your class inherit from `Controller` or `ApiController`?

Comment: It's WebAPI. So ApiController

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892819/ie8-treats-json-response-as-file-and-tries-to-download-it

Comment: tried it. Added 
 HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
and the problem still persists. unless I'm missing something

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult POST()
{
    HttpPostedFile file = null; ;
    string encodedString = //get the file contents, and get the base64 encoded string        
    ModelName obj= new ModelName();
    obj.characters = encodedString;
    return   Json(obj, "text/html");

}
```

**Update:**

Or change the content-type 
`Response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");`

example:

```
public JsonResult POST()
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = null; ;
        string encodedString = //get the file contents, and get the base64 encoded string        
        ModelName obj= new ModelName();
        obj.characters = encodedString;
        Response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
        return   Json(obj, "text/html");

    }
```

Comment: I've tried it. Still prompts me to download. It's something with the response headers

Comment: see my edit. It seems like Ie 8 doesn't know what is application/json

Comment: I might be horribly ignorant, but doesn't that use the System.Json dll? Which is for silverlight? I've tried JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), but it still doesn't work

Comment: are you using asp.net? mvc?

Comment: Or rather, how would I specify the "text/html" part? It's MVC4 so it's using the newtonsoft.Json reference

Comment: POST is return `ActionResult`? post the code of this action please

Comment: i've posted the relevant parts of the controller

Comment: see my edit. I changed the prototype of the function and return Json.

Comment: that Json() call...what is that under? I wasn't able to set it up exactly like that, so I tried something different. Updated, though it's still not working

Comment: JsonResult is from `System.Web.Mvc`

Comment: Yes I've included that. It's just not liking the Json(obj, "text/html"); part of it

so i've tried another, seemingly similar approach, but it still yields the same result

Comment: Ok so add this it must be working `response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");`
from `System.Net.Http.Headers`

Comment: I'm sorry, but where would that line go?

Comment: But the variable 'response' isn't being used anywhere. it would throw an exception

Comment: It's static like Request. Is it throwing an excpetion when you trying to access this variable?

Comment: Yea I see what you mean. I see the Request variable, but not the response one. It just says "the name response does not exist in the current contest"

Comment: try Response not response

Comment: use `System.Net.Http`