# IE8 jquery json response triggers download

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I want IE8 to work with the following piece of jquery that returns ajax request as json:

```
$.ajax({
        url: formAction,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: form,
        success: function(data) {
            closeBlocker();
            if (data.count != 0) {
                $('#divid').toggle('slow');
            } else {
                $("#anotherdiv").css('display', 'none');
            }
            processSearchResult(target, data);
            reloadMap(data);
        }
});
```

In all other browsers, this triggers a call to fetch data. In IE8, however, this results in a dialog box popping up that asks users if they want to download a file. It looks like this:

[image]

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114360/stupid-ie-prompts-to-open-or-save-json-result-which-comes-from-server) but havent been able to properly change the ContentType.

How can I do the same thing in IE8 without affecting other browsers? Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's related to [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type).

You have to tell browser to treat it as text/html. Then it will not try to download it, and will display it as text instead.

For this you can send `Content-type = "text/html"` in header.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this will solve your issue

[IE8 treats json response as file and tries to download it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892819/ie8-treats-json-response-as-file-and-tries-to-download-it)

I had the same problem when I try to do ajax calls from other domain, I introduced proxy with my URL and it got fixed.

Hope it helps.